# motion gesture and axis definition

Tags: mechanical-engineering, sensors, computer-engineering, computer-hardware

I read something about defining hand gesture, which include **mid-air hand gesture** (e.g a peace sign with the two fingers moving one after another), **touch-based gesture** (e.g. on touch screen), and **motion gesture** - manipulating the device (e.g. tilting a mobile phone sideway, pointing a mobile phone towards a person).

But I am not sure about how to categorise these gestures according to the following axis dimensions.

Some definition I saw were;

> **Single-axis** Motion occurs around a single axis
>
> "No matter the gesture is done in the mid-air context or on a surface,
>   if the movement is done only in one of the three coordinates, X, Y, or
>   Z, it is single-axis."
>
> **Double-axis** "If the gesture is performed on a surface, for example on a tabletop application, then the gesture has Double-Axis
>   dimensionality."
>
> **Tri-axis** Motion involves either translational or rotational motion, not both.
>
> "If only either of translation or rotation occurs in a gesture which
>   is performed in 3D space, it has tri-axis dimensionality."
>
> **Six-axis** Motion occurs around both rotational and translational axes

- what if I flip down a phone along one axis, it can be considered a rotation in 3D space? if yes then it would be tri-axis even it is movement done in one single axis?
- for sliding a phone along a plane and in a straight line, is it a tri-axis motion as it is translation n 3D, or is it a single-axis movement as it moves along one axis only?

Any examples would be very helpful. Thank you very much!

**references**

*definition in quote is from here: [TAXONOMY OF GESTURES IN HUMAN COMPUTER INTERACTION](https://library.ndsu.edu/ir/bitstream/handle/10365/23110/Vafaei_Taxonomy%20of%20Gestures%20in%20Human%20Computer%20Interaction.pdf?sequence=1)

definition not in quote signs is from here:
http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/1978942.1978971*